# GTK+ alignment and resizing with Glade

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtk#, glade

I am prototyping an application interface in Glade (GTK# 3.20 + C#) and use my CSS styles via CssProvider. I have this:

[image]

The problem is that I am using GTKLayout as my main container and I think it's the wrong way to create the UI. I am using this type of container because it give me the ability to resize and drag widgets as I want within the Glade during the prototyping. The bad thing is that widgets stuck at left top corner of the application window when I am resizing it. I made a min size for the window, but I want the UI to be adaptive when the window size is increasing. You can see the problem below:

[image]

I tried to create this UI with Box container, Grid container and so on. But I always had the same problem: the size of all the widgets was fixed (in Glade during the prototyping) and it looked like it was impossible to create the complex UI with it.

So, I want some experienced people to explain me a few things:

1. If I am using GTKLayout in a wrong way how should I organize my widgets (in which containers) to have the ability to resize them like I want (In Glade) and to have the same look like at my screenshot.
2. If it's not a bad practice to use GTKLayout, how should I solve the alignment problem to make an adaptive UI?
3. If it's a bad practice to use GTKLayout, how should I make an adaptive UI and with which containers?

Here is the structure of the window (yes, I am using Label widget to create color panels):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a look to the different [containers available](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html), run `gtk-demo` to see how are constructed the examples, use `gtk-inspector` on existing applications to know how they are laid out.

You may read also this layout "guide":

https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html

TLDR: Use a `GtkGrid`.

Comment: Yeeaah, you were right. I checked the Grid and after 30 minutes of manipulating I ported my UI to the new adaptive system. Thanks!
Resizing problem was solved by margins!

Answer (score 0):

GtkLayout is not designed to stretch, shrink and so forth. You probably want to set your GtkBox to `GTK_EXPAND(True)` and / or `GTK_FILL(True)` . In Glade select your label, button or child widget and look under the *Packing* tab.

Comment: And how can I make the same UI only with boxes and grid? It's impossible to resize widgets within that containers as I understand right.

Comment: One other thing besides the `expand` and `fill` is the `alignment` under the *Common* tab in Glade. This can move your box / grid to the center or edge, etc. Also check the homogeneous property of box / grid under the *General* tab. Furthermore, some of these are available to the button / label within a box / grid allowing you to make them smaller or centered, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I see it. But how can I resize the grid cell, for example? It seems that It has limits even without  homogeneous property.

Comment: Sometimes an `entry` controls the width for all widgets involved. Try setting the `width in chars` and `maximum width in chars` more than 0 under the *General* tab.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case the best option would be GtkFixed.